# Having trouble converting SQL query to Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have this query which works fine in `SQL` Server, but not in Access, and I'm having trouble converting it.  I've always heard that `JET` is missing some `TSQL` features, and I suppose complex joins is one of them.

```
SELECT C.[Position], TT.[Description] as TrainingType, T.ProgramTitle, T.ProgramSubTitle, T.ProgramCode, ET.CompletedDate
from HR_Curriculum C
LEFT JOIN HR_Trainings T ON C.TrainingID = T.TrainingID
LEFT JOIN HR_TrainingTypes TT ON T.TrainingTypeID = TT.TrainingTypeID

LEFT JOIN HR_EmployeeTrainings ET ON C.TrainingID = ET.TrainingID
                                 AND (ET.AvantiRecID IS NULL OR ET.AvantiRecID = '637')
where ( c.[Position] = 'Customer Service Representative'
      OR C.[Position] = 'All Employees')
order by [Position], Description, ProgramTitle
```

I tried putting the extra join clause down in the WHERE clause, but for some reason this does not yield the proper count of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your table alias are delacred with 'as'. Access doesn't like [tablename] [alias], instead try [tablename] as [alias]. I know the complex left joins shouldn't be a problem, but Access might be choking an the alias delcarations if it's returning some join error. I would also try quering out the restriction on the ET table, and then joining that to the larger query. I've noticed that trying to put restrictions on records involved in left or right joins will often not produce the correct records as Access will limit the set after the join.

Comment: And I'm also getting `JOIN expression not supported.`  So I think perhaps I can't do any filtering in the join.

Comment: You should be able to do the filtering, but you have to be careful as Access will apply the filter after the join which may or may not be what you intended. Just to be on the safe side I would create queries for the filtered information and join those queries if needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you have more than one `JOIN` in `ms-access` you need to wrap them with parenthesis like this:

```
SELECT C.[Position], TT.[Description] as TrainingType, T.ProgramTitle, T.ProgramSubTitle, T.ProgramCode, ET.CompletedDate
from (((HR_Curriculum C
LEFT JOIN HR_Trainings T ON C.TrainingID = T.TrainingID)
LEFT JOIN HR_TrainingTypes TT ON T.TrainingTypeID = TT.TrainingTypeID)

LEFT JOIN HR_EmployeeTrainings ET ON C.TrainingID = ET.TrainingID
                                 AND (ET.AvantiRecID IS NULL OR ET.AvantiRecID = '637'))
where ( c.[Position] = 'Customer Service Representative'
      OR C.[Position] = 'All Employees')
order by [Position], Description, ProgramTitle
```

or you will have the `Missing Operator` error

Comment: Getting `JOIN expression not supported`, so I think you are right on about the parens, but maybe I can't filter in the join.